# Is there any way to use regex or wild card to get objects from NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, xcode

i am adding values to `NSUserDefaults` at run time and making the keys as `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"decrement%@",course_id];`

i am setting the objects one by one is there any way i can get all the userdefaults object whose key start with "decrement"?

or i have to go in a loop and get object by making exact key one by one?

Note :- i accept down vote as an healthy way of criticism but do write the reason so that i can improve.

Comment: can you post the code in saving your data?

Comment: Guys trying your code will accept the one suited to my needs Thanku all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get all dictionary key of NSUserDefaults like this:

```
 NSArray *arrKeys = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys]
```

Now use NSPredicate for finding [NSString stringWithFormat:@"decrement%@",course_id]; value in arrKeys

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SELF like %@)",@"decrement"];
NSArray *keysLikeDecrement =
[arrKeys filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

NSPredicate *aPredicate =
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith 'decrement'"];
NSArray *beginWithDecrement =
[arrKeys filteredArrayUsingPredicate:aPredicate];

NSPredicate *bPredicate =
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains 'decrement'"];
NSArray *containsWithDecrement =[arrKeys filterUsingPredicate:bPredicate];
```

Answer (score 2):

`NSArray *keys = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys];`

You can then filter `keys` using `NSArray`s methods.

But it sounds like you should be using a different persistence mechanism, e.g. Coredata.

Comment: the number of values is really small 5 to 6 only but they vary based upon web services.

Comment: The recommendation to use a different persistence mechanism is because the data your storing is not what the `NSUserDefaults` is designed for. It seems like the data you want to store relates to the Model of your app. `NSUserDefaults` is general for storing incidental data such  as controller state. A simpler alternative than CoreData would be to store the data in a dictionary and save the dictionary to disk as a plist.

Answer (score 2):

Not the best/fastet solution, but using the available build-in blocks you could enumerate all the entries this way:

```
NSArray *keys = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys];
[[keys objectsAtIndexes:[keys indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSString *key, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [obj hasPrefix:@"myPrefix"];
}]] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:key];
}];
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer is 'NO', here is no way to do that. The user defaults are very much like a dictionary with key-value pairs. That said, you could create an array of 1000 numbers, get that array from the defaults, then ask it for the 900 value.